# Can I use 1 instead of asterisk for SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t1.mycol
FROM mytable t1
JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.id = t2.postid
ORDER BY value
LIMIT 10;
```

**It works well.**

Now I need to count the number of matched rows without the limitation. So I have've added this `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *` to the `select` statement and my query throws:

> `value` is **ambiguous** in the `order by` clause.

Why? And how can I fix it?

---

Noted that, when I use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1` instead of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *` in the `select` statement, then apperantly all fine. So, is it ok to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1`? (I'm asking this because that's `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *` in the documentation).

Comment: Does the query really work as expected when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is the only difference? It feels you just have two columns called `value`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes my query works well when I remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *`. Noted that the query you're seeing in my question is a simplified of my real query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a self-join, but you say the query does what you want.

Your problem is simply the lack of a qualified column name in the `order by`.  It has nothing to do with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t1.mycol
FROM mytable t1 JOIN
     mytable t2
     ON t1.id = t2.postid
ORDER BY t1.value
LIMIT 10;
```

I do not know why your original query would have worked.  It has the same ambiguous column name in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from mytable t1
JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.id = t2.postid
ORDER BY t1.value
LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The reason why you got the error was that, you are joining table with itself, so obviously, every column would occur twice. That's why the name is ambiguous. I added quelifier `t1`.

Comment: Still `value` is `ambiguous`. Noted that currently I'm selecting  `FOUND_ROWS()` in a separated query and I guess this is nothing to do with mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t1.* from mytable t1
JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.id = t2.postid
ORDER BY t1.value
LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```